# Eigenfunctions of the operator $Au:=-u''+ix^2u$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I need to find the eigenfunctions of the operator  $$Au:=-u''+ix^2u$$ if the domain of $A$ is the set of functions in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ with absolutely continuos derivatives $u,u'$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Can you give me any hint, please?.

Answer (score 0):

Well we want $Au = \lambda u$.

$-u'' + ix^2 u = \lambda u$ is a second order homogeneous ODE with linear coefficients which we can solve.

http://www.math.psu.edu/tseng/class/Math251/Notes-2nd%20order%20ODE%20pt1.pdf

Some notes on second order linear ODEs

Comment: Which page is helpful for an $ix^2$ coefficient?